# Input scroll when typing

Tags: javascript, html, input, overflow, typing

Is it possible to prevent that kind of thing:
I click on input, scroll down somewhere and when I type scroll jumps to input.
I want prevent that jump.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using this solution, as you might run into alot of compatibilty problems, you don't wan't to solve.

But you could add an keydown eventlister to your inputelement, which prevents the default action if the keyIdentifier starts with `"U+"` *(this way insert etc. will work)*

Then you create a string from the events, keyCode value make it lowercase if the shift key wasn't pressed, and insert it at the Cursors position.

```
inputElement.addEventListener ("keydown",function (e) {    

  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var element = e.srcElement || e.target;
  var ident = 0 | parseInt ( e.keyIdentifier.slice (-4) , 16)
  var cursorPos =  element.selectionStart || 0;
  var selectionEnd = element.selectionEnd || 0;

  if (key < 31 || key > 127 || ident !== key  || e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey ) { return true };

  if (key > 46 && key < 59 && e.shiftKey ) {
      key ^= 16;
  }

  if ( "U+" === e.keyIdentifier.slice (0,2) ) { //We only wan't to target text input values
      e.preventDefault() ; //this prevents the default action and with it the scrolling

      var characters = element.value.split ("");
          characters.splice (cursorPos,selectionEnd - cursorPos, String.fromCharCode (key)["to" + (e.shiftKey?"Upper":"Lower") + "Case"]());

      element.value = characters.join (""); //append the string value to the input

      cursorPos++;

      if(element.createTextRange) { 
            var range = element.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', cursorPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(element.selectionStart) {
                element.focus();
                element.setSelectionRange(cursorPos, cursorPos);
            }
            else {
                element.focus();
            }
        }

  }

});
```

So this is the updated version.

```
Known issues:

Shift + 0 -> `" "` 
Shift + 3 -> `"#"`

May not work on IE.
```

And there might be alot more. If there is an ismpler approach, i would use it, as this might need alot of compatibility code for different keyboard layouts.

But it's something to begin with

Comment: There are still some problems, i'll try to get it fixed

Comment: Ok, the most things are working like Backspace, Copy , Paste. Have to add insertion at the cursor

Comment: Inseraion at the right position works, have to move the cursor at the inserted position

Answer (score 0):

You could add an keydown eventListener and use `setTimeout` to scroll to the original position immediateley after the scrolling happens.

```
inputElement.addEventListener ("keydown" , function () {
   setTimeout (function () {
        window.scroll ( window.pageXOffset , window.pageYOffset)      
   },0)
});
```

*Only tested on chrome. You might notice flickering, so this is not an optimal solution either*

Answer (score -1):

One of the solution might be to remove the focus from the text box if scrolled down ,  but then the user cannot type.